# Grid - When should you switch from html to server side table processing?

Tags: ajax, jqgrid, datatables, flexigrid

,This question is likely subjective, but a lot of "grid" Javascript plugins have come out to help paginate and sort tables.  They usually work in 2 ways, the first and simplest is that it takes an existing HTML `<table>` and converts it into a sortable and searchable information.  The second is that it passes info to the server and has the server select info from the database to be displayed.

My question is this: **At what point (size wise) is it more efficient to use server-side processing vs displaying all the data and have the "grid plugin" convert it to a sortable/searchable table client-side?**

Using [datatables](http://datatables.net) as an example, I have to execute at least 3 queries to get total rows in the table, total filtered results for pagination, and the filtered results to be displayed for the specific selected page.  Then every time I sort, I am querying again.  Every time I move to another page, or search in the table, more queries.

If I was to pull the data once when the client visits the page, I would be executing a single query, and then formatting and pushing the results to the client all at once.  This increases the page size, and possibly delays loading of the page once it gets too big. The upside is there will only one query, and all the sorting, searching, and pagination is handled by the plugin, so no waiting for a response and no more queries.

If I was to have just a few rows, I imagine just pushing the formatted table data to the client at the page load would be the fastest.  But with thousands of rows, switching to server-side would be the most efficient way.

Where is the tipping point?  Is there a tipping point, or is server-side or client-side the way to go 100% of the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer on your question can be only subjective. So I explain how I personally understand the problem and give me recommendation.

In my opinion the data with 2-3 row and 3-4 column can be displayed in HTML table without usage any plugin. The data you display for the user the more important will be that the user will be able **to grasp** the information which will be displayed. So I think that the information for example have to be good formatted and marked with colors and icons for example. This with help to grasp information from probably 10 rows of data, but not much more. If you just display table with 100 rows or more then you **overtax** the user. The user will have to analyse the data to get any helpful information from the table. Scrolling of the data makes this not easier.

So I think that one should give the user comfortable or at least convenient interface **to sort and to filter** the data from the table. The exact interface is mostly the matter of taste. For example the grid can have an additional filter bar

[image]

For filtering and even for sorting of the data it's important to have not pure strings, but to be able to distinguish the data types like `integer` (10 should be after 9 and not between 1 and 2), `numbers` (correct interpret '.' and ',' inside of numbers), `dates` (`3/20/2012` should be grater as `4/15/2010`) and so on. If you just **convert** HTML table to some grid you will have problems with correct filtering or sorting. Even if you use pure *local* JavaScript data to display in grid it would be important to have datasource which has some kind of type information and then to create the grid based in the data. In the case you can gives date as JavaScript `Date` or as ISO 8601 string "2012-03-20" and in the grid display the data corresponds the specified formatter as `3/20/2012` or `20-Mar-2012`.

Whether you implement filtering, sorting and paging on the server side or on the client side is not really important for the user who open the page. It's important only that all works quickly enough. The exact choose of the grid plugin, the filtering (with filter toolbar or external controls) and styling of the grid depend on your taste and the project requirements.