# jQgrid tableToGrid() is ignoring colModel and ColNames in options

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I was going through the documentation and source code of jqGrid 4.3.1 when it comes for the `tableToGrid()` function and I found that the `ColModel` and `ColNames` are ignored when included in the `options` object as they are constructed from HTML table layout.

My question is there a way to force `tableToGrid()` to accept those two arrays `(ColModel,ColNames)` rather than construct them out of the HTML table, especially if the the table columns are known in advance.

When I went through the code, I found this portion in the code for `TableToGrid`

```
function tableToGrid(selector, options) {
...
...
// Build up the columnModel and the data
var colModel = [];
var colNames = [];
jQuery('th', jQuery(this)).each(function() {
    if (colModel.length === 0 && selectable) {
        colModel.push({
            name: '__selection__',
            index: '__selection__',
            width: 0,
            hidden: true
        });
        colNames.push('__selection__');
    } else {
        colModel.push({
            name: jQuery(this).attr("id") || jQuery.trim(jQuery.jgrid.stripHtml(jQuery(this).html())).split(' ').join('_'),
            index: jQuery(this).attr("id") || jQuery.trim(jQuery.jgrid.stripHtml(jQuery(this).html())).split(' ').join('_'),
            width: jQuery(this).width() || 150
        });
        colNames.push(jQuery(this).html());
    }
});
```

However, my hack would consider these changes

```
    function tableToGrid(selector, options) {
...
...
// Build up the columnModel and the data
if(options.hasOwnProperty("colModel") && options.hasOwnProperty("colNames")) {
    var colModel = options.colModel;
    var colNames = options.colNames;
} else {
    var colModel = [];
    var colNames = [];
    jQuery('th', jQuery(this)).each(function() {
                    if (colModel.length === 0 && selectable) {
                    colModel.push({
                    name: '__selection__',
                    index: '__selection__',
                    width: 0,
                    hidden: true
                    });
                    colNames.push('__selection__');
                    } else {
                    colModel.push({
                    name: jQuery(this).attr("id") || jQuery.trim(jQuery.jgrid.stripHtml(jQuery(this).html())).split(' ').join('_'),
                    index: jQuery(this).attr("id") || jQuery.trim(jQuery.jgrid.stripHtml(jQuery(this).html())).split(' ').join('_'),
                    width: jQuery(this).width() || 150
                    });
                    colNames.push(jQuery(this).html());
                    }
    });
}
```

I just would like to know if there's an easier way (may be an option I missed) that would enforce such behaviour without the need to adjust the source code.

The reason I am doing this in the first place is to force the `datefmt` option for some of the fields as they are ignored by the jQgrid causing issues with the search functionality. If @Oleg can give some insight about this, it will highly appreciated.

Cheers, N.

Comment: [What do you mean exactly with `colModel` and `colNames` ignored?](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/4esFf/)

Comment: They aren't into consideration when constructing the jqGrid from the existing HTML table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main your problem is that you use `tableToGrid` at all. I find the question about the common usage or architecture as technical question.

If you have *typed* data like numbers, dates, currency and so on you want probably that the data will be correctly sorted, by jqGrid for example. Parsing of localized data from the HTML table and unformatting of the data is not the best way. You save your time if you would create jqGrid *directly*. You should provide the input data in `data` parameter. In the way the data will be easy and safe read, sorted and paged. You can easy include toolbar filtering or advanced searching or some other searching of filtering. All will good work only if you will provide jqGrid *pure data*.

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9795116/315935) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg. So I take that I have two options: either I should extract the data from the table and pass it into the `data` parameter, say in a form of function that reads the table `<td>` so I have the freedom to change the formatting in advance or the second option is to disregard `tableToGrid()` and just use `jQgrid` with information with other `dataType`, other than `local || clientside` like `JSON` moving the task of data formatting to the server side, did I get that correctly?

Comment: @nawar: Even if you would use `datatype: 'json'` you should not format the data on the server. You should send pure numbers, dates in language independent ISO 8601 and so on. You should use either [predefined](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) or [custom formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) and format the data on the client side. I recommend you to use `tableToGrid` only with pure text data inside or don't use it at all.

Comment: @nawar: The code of [tableToGrid](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.tbltogrid.js) is not really complex. You can debug it to see all possibilities which you has. In the practice it will be used only by people how starts working with jqGrid and try to hold the existing schema. The more features of jqGrid you will be need the more clear will be to change the input which you use to *pure data* either as local JavaScript data or the data loaded from the server per Ajax.

Comment: Okay, I will take your suggestions into consideration. Thanks @Oleg for your quick help.

Comment: @nawar: You are welcome! I gave you my personal point of view on the subject.